# Sum a sequence of positive and negative fraction

Tags: c++

I have a homework to make an algorithms for sum this sequence : `S = 1 - 1/2 + 1/4 - 1/6 + 1/8 - 1/10 + ... + 1/2n` if the user input 2 the sum will be `1 - 1/2 = 1/2` and etc.

Here is my coding :

```
int main() {

    int num, N, k;
    double S;
    cout << "enter the sequence : ";
    cin >> N;
    for (num = 1, k = 0, S = 1; num <=N; num++) {
        num++;
        k=+2;
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            S -= 1/k;
        } else {
            S += 1/k;
        }
    }
    cout << "The sum is " << S;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm so confused why the sum always refer to 1 ?? Can anyone explain to me why this happen??

Answer (score 7):

Try `1./k` — otherwise integer division of 1 by anything will yield zero. (and see the other answer about `=+` vs `+=` typo).

Comment: Don't forget that will yield infinity if `k` is zero.

Comment: @Electro Yes but his loop code does not allow zero to be a value

Comment: @jack23 - re *thanks, it worked now*: You acknowledged in words that this answer is correct. So you should accept this answer.

Comment: The problem with accepting is that there are two answers pointing out different problems ;-) I'd vote for @mathematician1975, because he has lower rep.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Actually I think he should accept your answer as integer division is a common pitfall for newbies and your answer likely to be of more use to a future visitor.

Answer (score 3):

In your loop you have this

```
k=+2;
```

so you assign the value 2 to `k` every iteration. You probably want

```
k+=2;
```

also take heed of the integer division problem highlighted in the other answer

Answer (score 1):

```
for(num = 1, sum = 1; num <=N; num++){
    if(num%2==0){
        sum += 1/(num*2);
    }else{
        sum -= 1/(num*2);
    }
}
```

That should do it, provided the nth term in your sequence is `(1/((n-1)*2))`.

EDIT: As pointed out below, when performing division, one of the operands needs to be non integer to prevent the result from being an integer. The correction to my attempt above would be:

```
for(num = 1, sum = 1; num <=N; num++){
    if(num%2==0){
        sum += 1.0/(num*2);
    }else{
        sum -= 1.0/(num*2);
    }
}
```

http://codepad.org/KgGAxKxS

Comment: This still has the integer division problem whenever `(num*2)` is greater than the numerator (1 in this case)

Comment: @Asad, no, sum being non-integer doesn't help the division.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I was assuming the problem stemmed from the fact that the result would be rounded to an integer. How could this be fixed? (haven't used C++ before so I apologise for the noob-ness)

Comment: Not both sides of the division should be integers, one of them should be a double, thus either `num` sould be a double (which makes `num+2` a double), or the `1` (can be solved by just typing `1.0` which is a double).

Comment: @Asad, don't you read other answers? :) I've provided a solution to this problem and it's one character shorter than `1.0` ;-) (not that I dislike the `1.0` solution).

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I did read (and upvote) your answer and it is indeed shorter, but I can't just repost your answer verbatim can I?

Comment: No, I was referring to your question about how could this be fixed, not your answer. Speaking of voting, I'm taking back my downvote.

Comment: BTW, about making things shorter (I think that was one of your objectives, which I find great) — `sum += (1.-2*(num%2))/(2*num)` instead of `if` ;-) This is about having fun, not a proper answer, tho ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker That was because I didn't understand (at the time) *why* that worked. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker that's pretty clever. The typical route would be to use the ternary operator.

Comment: @Asad, yes, but avoiding `if` and using ternary is kinda cheating ;-)